# How can I add a Python Object to new column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over all rows in a Pandas Dataframe and I want to add a couple of new columns while iterating over each row.
One column is an integer, the other is a Python object (class MyClass).

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    ... calculate myinteger and myclass_object ...

    df.loc[df.index[index], 'breakout'] = myinteger
    df.loc[df.index[index], 'object'] = myclass_object
```

But I get:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xd3\x07\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00'
```

I think it is related to Pandas trying to figure out value of myclass_object, when dtype shall be set up to object but I am not sure.

Comment: You can verify what you're thinking by commenting out the offending line and running the code. I however think that the cause of the error lies elsewhere and not with pandas. It's more helpful for others looking to answer your question if a complete error traceback is included.

Comment: Theoffending line is clearly the one that adds myclass_object, because myclass_object is a Python object of a custom class. If I type `1` instead of myclass_object then there is no problem. I am adding that type of objects to columns using apply and lambda in other areas of the code. It seems that .loc tries to guess the type without success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try this:

```
for i in df.index.tolist():
    df.at[i,'breakout'] = myinteger
    df.at[i, 'object'] = myclass_object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like do it with `pandas` I recommend assign it after for loop

```
myi=[]
myo=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    myi.append(myinteger)
    myo.append(myclass_object)
```

Then

```
df['breakout'] = myi
df['object'] = myo
```

Comment: The object depends on the specific row.